# Defining inline data for reference objects in Ext-js

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can I load data inline for an [`Ext.data.Model`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) where one of the fields is a reference? See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ji9

```
 Ext.define('Address', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: ['address', 'city', 'state']
 });

 Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: ['name', {
         name: 'address',
         reference: 'Address'
     }]
 });

 var data = {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Juan',
     address: {
         id: '5',
         address: '22 Main st',
         city: 'Somerville',
         state: 'MA'
     }
 };

var user = new User(data);

// Outputs Address is undefined
console.log('Address is ', user.getAddress().get('city')  );

// Outputs {"id":{"id":"5","address":"22 main st","city":"Somerville","state":"MA"}}
// Instead of {"id":"5","address":"22 main st","city":"Somerville","state":"MA"}
console.log(JSON.stringify( user.getAddress().data ) );
```

I know I could do `user.setAddress(new Address(data.address));` but I need something generic

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`Ext.data.Model`'s reader](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json) for associations to get created correctly

```
var user = User.getProxy().getReader().readRecords(data).records[0];
// Outputs Somerville
console.log('Address is ', user.getAddress().get('city')  );

// Outputs {"id":"5","address":"22 main st","city":"Somerville","state":"MA"}
console.log(JSON.stringify( user.getAddress().data ) );
```